# This question still needs 0 vote(s) from other users to close

Tags: support, flags, review

I frequently review posts in the first posts review queue, and sometimes, when I flag a post for moderator attention, I get the message, "This question still needs 0 vote(s) from other users to close". Does that mean that the question is now closed? (It isn't right now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352596/should-i-develop-websites-with-visual-studio-2005-2008-or-visual-web-developer)?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I tried for a while but was unable to reproduce what you're seeing in the screenshot. We'll keep looking into it, but in the meantime, it'd be helpful if you could check for js errors on the page next time you run into it.

Comment: @Emmett I'll try to remember to check for js errors when I encounter this next. Could it be that you're a mod so if you vote to close something, it gets closed immediately, but since I can't even cast close votes yet, it tries to take my flag as a close vote?

Comment: I impersonated a non-mod with lower rep when I tried to reproduce it.